# Active Directory login Errordd

Tags: active-directory

I've configured an AD-DS with two user accounts. then I logged in to these accounts using my laptop separately. But after server shut down still I can logged in to these two accounts using client machine. why is this happen ?

Comment: Cached Credentials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows caches (stores a local copy (of the hash)) of your AD credentials for just this situation.  If you are part of a domain but want to use your laptop when you aren't connected, the cached password lets you log in.

Comment: So what do I need to avoid this ?

Comment: @ISuru  You don't want to, actually, but I believe you may be able to set the number of remembered logins to 0 in the GPO that controls this setting.